# Getting System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: 'Could not find a part of the path' after folder creation

Tags: asp.net-mvc, file-upload, filesystems, ioexception, ioerror

I am getting the error ***System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: 'Could not find a part of the path' *** after creating the directory in the file system. What I am trying to do is to create the folder in the file system and then add images files to it based off of the user's input. I am getting this error while trying to upload images after creating the directory. (Line: file.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(filePath));)

View:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="addPortfolioModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="addPortfolioModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-xlg" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title">Add Portfolio</h5>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
        </div>
        @using (Html.BeginForm("AddPortfolio", "Admin", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
        {
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 modal-form-margin">
                            @Html.Label("title", "Title: ")
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 modal-form-margin">
                            @Html.TextBox("title", null, new { type = "text", @class = "w-100", required = "required" })
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 modal-form-margin">
                            @Html.Label("description", "Description: ")
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 modal-form-margin">
                            @Html.TextArea("description", null, new { type = "text", @class = "w-100", @id = "description" })
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 modal-form-margin">
                            @Html.Label("images", "Image(s): ")
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 modal-form-margin">
                            <input type="file" name="imageFiles" id="imageFiles" required multiple />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add Portfolio</button>
            </div>
        }
    </div>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
    [ValidateInput(false)]
    public ActionResult AddPortfolio(string title, string description, HttpPostedFileBase[] ImageFiles)
    {
        if (!checkLoginCredentials())
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Login", "Home");
        }
        else if (ImageFiles.Count() < 1)
        {
            TempData["imagesFail"] = true;
        }
        else
        {
            string dir = "Content/img/portfolio/" + title;
            if (!Directory.Exists(dir))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(Server.MapPath("~/" + dir));
                List<PortfolioImageModel> images = new List<PortfolioImageModel>();
                string extension = "";
                string fileName = "";
                int orderNumCounter = 1;

                int portfolioResult = siteServices.addPortfolio(title, description);
                if(portfolioResult > 0)
                {
                    int portfolioId = siteServices.getPortfolioIdByTitle(title);

                    foreach (var file in ImageFiles)
                    {
                        if (file != null)
                        {
                            if (file.ContentLength > 0)
                            {
                                if (Path.GetExtension(file.FileName).ToLower() == ".jpg" || Path.GetExtension(file.FileName).ToLower() == ".png" || Path.GetExtension(file.FileName).ToLower() == ".jpeg" || Path.GetExtension(file.FileName).ToLower() == ".gif")
                                {
                                    extension = Path.GetExtension(file.FileName);
                                    var filePath = Path.Combine(dir, file.FileName);
                                    file.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(filePath));

                                    PortfolioImageModel temp = new PortfolioImageModel();
                                    temp.setImgLoc(fileName);
                                    temp.setPortfolioId(portfolioId);
                                    temp.setOrderNum(orderNumCounter);

                                    images.Add(temp);
                                    orderNumCounter++;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    int imagesResult = siteServices.addPortfolioImages(images);
                    if(imagesResult < 1)
                    {
                        TempData["imagesFail"] = true;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    TempData["databaseConnectionFail"] = true;
                }


            }
            else
            {
                TempData["portfolioExists"] = true;
            }
        }

        return RedirectToAction("Portfolio", "Admin");
    }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Does the title have any spaces?

Comment: @JasonRoner Yes they can

Comment: It may or not be the issue, but I would suggest not allowing any spaces in the directory at all to save headaches.  So, I'd do this:  string dir = "Content/img/portfolio/" + title.Trim().Replace(" ", "_");  I would also work on filtering out any non-alphanumerics in case the user tries to do this

Comment: @JasonRoner I do agree with you, not having spaces in the directory is something I should fix along with filtering out non-alphanumerics. I went ahead and implemented the trimming of spaces, however I am still receiving the same error.

Comment: @MDBerry just for testing, will you add those folders as part of the solution in visual studio? Then try to access them via the program. I'm aware that you want to access them after creation but this test might help with creating a solution.

Comment: @JerdineSabio My client has give me actual content for testing, so I could have that as part of the solution at launch, however I do not understand how that can help at least now because if the folder is already created and included in the project, I have had success, but when I have created it within the controller, that's when I get the error. When stopping the application on the error, I can see the folder has been created within the solution, but it is not included in the solution, maybe that is the issue? But then wouldn't that affect the app when publish?

Answer (score 1):

The issue was that the path passed into the file.SaveAs() method was searching for the path of the filePath variable inside of the controller's view folder. Here was the fix (will be simplifying the code going forward:

```
if (Path.GetExtension(file.FileName).ToLower() == ".jpg" || Path.GetExtension(file.FileName).ToLower() == ".png" || Path.GetExtension(file.FileName).ToLower() == ".jpeg" || Path.GetExtension(file.FileName).ToLower() == ".gif")
                                {
                                    extension = Path.GetExtension(file.FileName);
                                    fileName = file.FileName;
                                    file.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("../" + dir + "/" + fileName));

                                    PortfolioImageModel temp = new PortfolioImageModel();
                                    temp.setImgLoc(dir + "/" + fileName);
                                    temp.setOrderNum(orderNumCounter);

                                    images.Add(temp);
                                    orderNumCounter++;
                                }
```

Comment: I had a similar error, it end up that one of the directories was wrongly spelled, debugging usually helps to find out this, It was hard for me to see it, I had to use a compare text tool

Answer (score 0):

Just change this:

```
 string dir = "Content/img/portfolio/" + title.Trim().Replace(" ", "_");
  if (!Directory.Exists(Server.MapPath("~/" + dir)))
    {
      //Your Code
    }
```